# How is MOQ.Setup working in this scenario - when called multiple times?

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I'm looking for an explanation of exactly how `moq's Setup` method works when setting up a mock object that will be called multiple times from the 'system under test' (sut)

For example:

If I have a mock object setup and call my Sut method.

```
var inputParamObject = new inputParamObject();

this.mock.Setup(x => x.MethodCall(inputParam).Returns(this.mock.Object);

Sut.WithCallLoopingMethodThatCallsTheMockObject();
```

Now, the real code I'm working on is legacy and pretty impossible to show here  so this is unfortunately a simple representation of what I think is happening.

The issue, I'm seeing is that if the `inputParamObject` is used for the first iteration of the loop, it returs the correct mock object.  However, on the second iteration, it returns null.

If I change the above code to use a second InputParamObject, it will return the mock again and my test will pass:

```
var inputParam = new InputParam();
var inputParam2 = new InputParam();

this.mock.Setup(x => x.MethodCall(inputParam).Returns(this.mock.Object);
this.mock.Setup(x => x.MethodCall(inputParam2).Returns(this.mock.Object);

Sut.WithCallLoopingMethodThatCallsTheMockObject();
```

I thought that the second setup on the mock would simply overwrite the first but it seems not to be the case.  I also know that I can setup like this instead and the test will pass.

```
this.mock.Setup(x => x.MethodCall(It.IsAny<InputParamObject>).Returns(this.mock.Object);
```

I apologise that this is contrived example and perhaps more detail is required to understand but,

Can anyone tell me exactly what is happening when I have one Setup call versus two in this example?

Also a pointer to specific reference material for this situation would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never experienced any issues with calling a method of a mock object multiple times. I think there might be a couple of other reasons for your tests to fail.

1. You seem to have a single instance of the mock object per test fixture. Other tests might have side effects on your mock object setup. Try creating an own instance in each test. You may find userful the Unit Testing Context Pattern
   http://java.dzone.com/articles/introducing-unit-testing
2. Your method WithCallLoopingMethodThatCallsTheMockObject might send different instances of inputParamObject into MethodCall. Maybe you have to override the Equals method of inputParamObject.

My code that ran successfully is below.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        const int SERVICE_ID = 123;
        ParamObject callParam = new ParamObject(42);
        var fakeService = new Mock<IService>();

        fakeService.Setup(call => call.MethodCall(callParam)).Returns(fakeService.Object);
        fakeService.Setup(call => call.Id).Returns(SERVICE_ID);
        Processor sut = new Processor(fakeService.Object, callParam);

        // --- Act
        sut.WithCallLoopingMethodThatCallsTheMockObject();
    }
}

public interface IService
{
    int Id { get; }
    IService MethodCall(ParamObject param);
}

public class ParamObject
{
    private int _id = 0;

    public ParamObject(int id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }
}

public class Processor
{
    private IService _service;
    private ParamObject _serviceCallParam;

    public Processor(IService service, ParamObject serviceCallParam)
    {
        _service = service;
        _serviceCallParam = serviceCallParam;
    }

    public void WithCallLoopingMethodThatCallsTheMockObject()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
        {
            IService srv = _service.MethodCall(_serviceCallParam);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Iteration {0:00}, service instance id={1}", i, srv.Id));
        }
    }
}
```